# Upgrading django version from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: python, django

This is not going to be a code base query,this is going to be a simple query for discussion from a novice django developer.I am not sure whether i am going to get down votes for this question,but to be honest, this is a very serious issue/decision for me.

I have a running  project powered by django 1.5 and yet not been completed,now i am going to start another project and i want to do it with django 1.7 version.My question is,if i upgrade my django version from 1.5 to 1.7.will it do any harm to my previous project powered by django 1.5 and will i continue the previous project with django 1.7 version?

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Pythons [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

They allow you to manage installed Python modules on a per-project basis.

Comment: can i apply virtual environments locally?

Comment: @Tanveer Yes, each virtual environment lives in a directory.